# jQuery capture mousemove when a certain key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to capture event if suppose key <kbd>H</kbd> is pressed and mouse is moving over some div.

**`KeyPressed` and `mouseMoving` both have to be true.**

https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/1Loeh2pn/

**Code:**

```
$('#header').on("mousemove keydown", function(e) {
  //only print if key 'H' is pressed and mouse is moving over $('#header')
  if (e.type === 'mousemove' && e.which === 72) {
    console.log('working');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helpful for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/1Loeh2pn/3/

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").hover(function() {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 72){
                console.log('H')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have noticed i have to click div to trigger hover .. works fine as expected